# Neural network: predictions are just the same prediction despite changes in the model parameters

Tags: r, torch, tidymodels

I'd like to fit a neural network using `brulee` but despite the several changes in the model parameters (changes in all the parameters), I always have the almost same value in the predictions. In my case:

```
# Open the data set
data_train_sub <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/cc_test_ds.csv")

# Model parameters
hidden_units <-c(4)
epochs <-c(50)
dropout <-c(0.01)
learn_rate <- c(0.01)
activation <- c("relu")
penalty <- c(0.01)
validation <-c(0.80)

# Training data set
data_train <- data_train_sub[1:1250,]

# Validation data set
data_test <-  data_train_sub[1251:1500,]

# Model fitting
fit <- brulee_mlp(x = as.matrix(data_train[, 2:ncol(data_train)]),
               y = data_train$cc,
               hidden_units = hidden_units,
               epochs = epochs, dropout = dropout, learn_rate = learn_rate, activation = activation,
               penalty = penalty,validation=validation)
#Plot                
predict(fit, data_test) %>%
   bind_cols(data_test) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = .pred, y = cc)) +
   geom_abline(col = "green") +
   geom_point(alpha = .3) +
   lims(x = c(0, 1.0), y = c(0, 1.0)) +
   coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image: nn]

This sounds strange to me. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite sure yet but two things stick out: there are two extreme outliers in the training set (rows 64 and 162) and you are putting 80% of your data into _validations_ (maybe you meant 20%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues were the outliers mentioned above and that you needed to standardize your predictors to be on the same scale.

Although the model doesn't fit great, here is a modified version with more complexity (but gives different predicted values). I also added PCA which helps a small amount (but you could leave that step out of the recipe).

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(brulee)
```

```r
tidymodels_prefer()
theme_set(theme_bw())
options(pillar.advice = FALSE, pillar.min_title_chars = Inf)
```

```r
data_train_sub <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/cc_test_ds.csv")

# Model parameters
hidden_units <-c(50) # more hidden units
epochs <-c(500) # more iterations
dropout <-c(0) # since we are using penalization, no dropout
learn_rate <- c(0.01)
activation <- c("relu")
penalty <- c(0.01)
validation <-c(0.20) # hold out 20%

# Training data set
data_train <- data_train_sub[1:1250,]

# There are two extreme outliers: 
data_train_2 <- data_train %>% slice(-c(64, 162))

# Validation data set
data_test <-  data_train_sub[1251:1500,]

rec <- 
  recipe(cc ~ ., data = data_train_2) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_predictors()) 

set.seed(1)
# Model fitting
fit <- brulee_mlp(rec, data = data_train_2,
                  hidden_units = hidden_units,
                  epochs = epochs, dropout = dropout, learn_rate = learn_rate, activation = activation,
                  penalty = penalty,validation=validation)

# check convergence
autoplot(fit)
```

[image]

```r
#Plot                
predict(fit, data_test) %>%
  bind_cols(data_test) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = .pred, y = cc)) +
  geom_abline(col = "green") +
  geom_point(alpha = .3) +
  lims(x = c(0, 1.0), y = c(0, 1.0)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>